# How to log into my auto-created PayPal developer sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

On the Developer portal, PayPal automatically created a sandbox account for me with the email address of **myname*-developer*@gmail.com**. This account is working fine - I can use its API key, pay to it from my manually created buyers account etc.

I just don't know how to log into this account on sandbox.paypal.com. When I try to use my standard PayPal password it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should the same password as your LIVE account.
If it does not work, try to change the password in `developer.paypal.com->Applications->Sandbox Accounts->Profile->Change Password.`[image]

Comment: Thanks. My standard password didn't work, however, I was able to change it as you suggested and successfully logged in.